# Set default editor

Tags: bash, shell, cat

I would like to configure a program named [howdy](https://github.com/boltgolt/howdy) which allows you to login using your face.
For this I need to edit the config file to add the path to my camera.
However when I execute `sudo howdy config` it opens nano despit the fact that I added

```sh
export EDITOR='code' 
export VISUAL='code'
```

to my .bashrc file. It is supposed to edit it in my default editor.
When I do anything like `sudo howdy config|cat` or `sudo howdy config|code` it still opens nano. Does anyone know why this is the case?

(also I don't know how to copy text in nano and none of the [combinations mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507022/copy-text-from-nano-editor-to-shell) don't work)

Answer (score 1):

1. `sudo` doesn't preserve the environment (see `man sudo`). You can use `sudo -E` to request environment preservation. Use at your own risk, there's a reason the environment is not preserved.
2. `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` are just hints to the program, each program may use or ignore them at their leisure. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/boltgolt/howdy/blob/beta/howdy/src/cli/config.py) of howdy, it actually reads the EDITOR variable, so after preserving the environment, it should hopefully work.

Comment: Thank you very much. Why would you not want the environment to be preserved for Sudo commands?

Comment: @TheFibonacciEffect `man 5 sudoers`, [command environment](https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/sudoers.man/#Command_environment).